# How to change the @Cacheable condition field at runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, aop

I am using Redis with Spring Boot and I want to make a flag to enable cache at runtime by AOP

I tried to change the condition filed to "false" from AOP but it is not working and the caching is still saving data to memory.

```
  public void disableCache(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    method.setAccessible(true);
    Cacheable myAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Cacheable.class);
    InvocationHandler handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(myAnnotation);
    Field field;
    try {
        field = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Object> memberValues;
    try {
        memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) field.get(handler);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    memberValues.put("condition", "false" );
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nobody can debug plain prose. Programmers debug code. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. If you feel unable to do that, please help yourself by reading some documentation or tutorials like [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing your question, adding sample code showing what you tried. Now I can answer:

Annotations are by definition a compile-time thing. They cannot be changed during runtime. Even if you use dirty tricks like reflection, it might not have a permanent effect. Besides, you should not assume that each annotation is re-evaluated each time a method is called. If Spring is a smartly designed framework, which I guess it is, it does that once while wiring the application. Either way, you are on the wrong path. Turn around quickly!

You still have options: Either you can do caching manually, if you want it to be super dynamic. Or you can use conditional caching, utilising SpEL like this:

```java
@CachePut(value="addresses", condition="#customer.name=='Tom'")
```

or

```java
@CachePut(value="addresses", unless="#result.length()<64")
```

See this [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial#conditional-caching) for more information.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial.